# Probability textbook advice: Borovkov or Klenke

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request

I’m looking for a fairly comprehensive, modern, measure-theoretic text on probability theory.

I’ve found Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course by Achim Klenke and  Probability Theory by Borovkov.

If someone is familiar with both can they provide some pros and cons?